# Making new SQL Statment without canceling current one

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, exploit

Is there some way to completely change the SQL statement while writing it:

Let's say I have this:

```
SELECT * from `table1` WHERE `column1` LIKE '%%'
```

But now I decide I actually want to `SELECT` something completely different, like `table2` e.g., could I continue writing (i.e. without deleting what I've written this far and without making a completely new statement (seperated by a semicolon)) and still get the content of `table2`?
 (which I would normally get by writing `SELECT * from table2`)?

I'm asking cause I'm fascinated by SQL injection and wonder how far you can go with it.

Comment: How is the query currently being built?

Comment: @Tim what if he were to click his mouse near `table1` ... close to the 1 part

Comment: Let's say, you can enter a search query that is inserted between the two `%` signs.

Comment: @Drew I was thinking more along the lines of replacing `table1` with `table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.id = t2.id`, but his code _might_ protect against this, assuming he is using the right tool.

Comment: This cannot seriously be a question about sql injection, a fresh one, when volumes here have been written about wedging in injection, can it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the query backwards. An sql injection is about amending the query starting from the point where actual injection occurs.